# How to check if both radio buttons are not checked

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to validate those radio buttons and notify the user if both of them are unchecked. My function RadioValidation() doesn't work, how can I fix it? Thank you!

```js
    function RadioValidation() {
        var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="shipmethod"]:checked');
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            if (!buttons[i].checked) {
                alert("NOT CHECKED")
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<label class="radiner">
  PickUp
  <input type="radio" name="shipmethod" value="PickUp" required>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="radiner">
  Delivery
  <input type="radio" name="shipmethod" value="Delivery" required>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
                            
<button class="btn txt-center" type="submit" id="checkout" onclick="RadioValidation()">Payment</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```js
function RadioValidation() {
    var buttons = document.querySelector('input[name="shipmethod"]:checked');
    if(buttons)
      console.log(buttons.value);
    else
      alert('Nothing selected');
}
```

```html
<label class="radiner">
  PickUp
  <input type="radio" name="shipmethod" value="PickUp" required>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="radiner">
  Delivery
  <input type="radio" name="shipmethod" value="Delivery" required>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
                            
<button class="btn txt-center" type="submit" id="checkout" onclick="RadioValidation()">Payment</button>
```